# VTK crashes with QT Plugins qjpeg.dll

Tags: qt, plugins, vtk

I am developing a software using Qt Library 4.8.4, VTK6.0, OpenCV2.4.3. CMake and MSVC2010 are used to build and compile the project.

Only for the Release version, it crashes at runtime. I figured out that the problems is caused by C:\Qt\4.8.4\plugins\imageformats\qjpeg4.dll and qjpeg4.lib. The software runs perfectly if these files cannot be located (renamed or removed from their directory).

Since I have nothing to do with this plugin at all, I have tried reconfiguring CMakeList for VTK and my project to disable this plugin by removing the path. This doesn't solve the problem. Therefore, I assume that this plugin is called by some dependencies of QT.

Any idea to solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: If you built everything with the same compiler did you use the INSTALL target to install VTK?  If so remember this can limit what configuration you can use for your application. It is not safe to use a Release dll in a debug application or a Debug dll in a release application. Both will cause you to have more than 1 heap which ends up causing your application to have random crashes allocating or deallocating memory since the heaps are independent and you can not safely allocate ram in one heap and free it in a different.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the problem is not caused by those plugins, the problem is caused elsewhere and gets those plugins to crash. Maybe you have a broken jpeg file that gets loaded. But most likely you're facing a memory bug. You'd need to compile it under linux and run using valgrind to see what's up.

I hope that you did recompile all parts of this project with the same C++ compiler?

Comment: "I hope that you did recompile all parts of this project with the same C++ compiler?" Very important.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Yes, I do have every part compiled with the same compiler and be very careful with debug and release dll. There is no jpeg loaded by the time that the software crashes. I agree that it might be a memory bug. Just wonder if there is any way to track it down in Windows?